# Information missing from external SSD [exFAT] after ejection

Tags: windows-10, ssd

When I copy new files to the drive, and after finishing copying I disconnect the drive form my USB connection - the new files don't appear after I reconnect (this problem does not happen if I use "safe eject" before disconnecting).

Same thing happen if I DELETE files (they reappear).

The problem also occurs when computer put to sleep (while SSD connected).

Why this is happening? it is first time for me (after using windows more than 20 years and never using "safe eject").

Comment: So start using "safe eject", it exists for a reason.

Comment: ↑ Can't say fairer than that. You're not giving the OS time to flush the write buffer. That's why we have safe eject. You can get away with it on 'cheap' media - SD cards, USB sticks because they don't 'trust' the system in the same way. Don't attempt it with anything you could describe as a 'hard drive'. You've got away with it lightly so far - you could kill the entire partition if you get unlucky.

Comment: Though you can set the drive to be "removable," i.e., eliminate write-caching, https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/111728-how-make-disk-drive-removable.html , you'll find the drive may be *slower**.

Comment: @Tetsujin So theoretically if I "give it time" (lets say, 5 minutes), than there's no need for "safe eject"?

Comment: Not necessarily. It may or may not have flushed the cache. If you tell it to dismount, you make sure it does.